# How to custom ads banner for mobile?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

***How to custom admob banner  ? like as picture***

[image]

---

---

***in my code :***

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/Banner_ads">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

***banner is showing :***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the new NativeAdvanced Ad format.